# In a transistor, why can't current flow through the main circuit even if the control circuit is off?

Tags: transistors

This is a npn transistor
[image: npn transistor picture]

The green part of the circuit is the control circuit. If I remove it and keep only the white part, the main circuit, the electrons should still be able to push through the junctions and flow through the transistor to come back to the cell right?

I was reading about transistors and found that increasing the voltage of the control circuit will allow more current to flow through the transistor, because if only the control circuit was there, then the electrons would be able to the push through one junction. If both the control circuit and main circuit are there then the main circuit's electrons can go through that one junction easier so more current can flow. If the cell in the main circuit already has a high voltage then this shouldn't matter as the electrons in the transistor are already being pushed into and out the holes at the maximum extent.

Am I going wrong in my reasoning that the control circuit only varies the current going through the main circuit and does not turn it on and off?

Answer (score 0):

The "main circuit", as you call it, cannot cause current to flow all the way across the transistor (from collector to emitter) by itself since the collector-base junction is reverse biased. This blocks current in the same way that a diode blocks current flow from cathode to anode: the electric field in the depletion region is trying to pull electrons out of a P-type base where those charge carriers are scarce. But if you were to *inject* electrons into the base with another forward biased junction (the base-emitter junction), then they can be "stolen" by the collector-base junction's electric field before they can recombine.

Comment: When only the main circuit is there, in the emitter-base junction why can't the electrons from the emitter go into the base. Once the electrons reaches the base it can go to the collector?

Comment: If the base is left floating, leakage current between the emitter and base (the phenomenon you describe) will cause the base to reach the same voltage as the emitter and current flow will cease. Afterwards, since there are no charge carriers entering the base, there is no concentration gradient across the base, so no more charge carriers reach the base-collector depletion region (other than thermally generated carriers that can reach the depletion region before they recombine).

Comment: Quote: "inject electrons into the base with another forward biased junction (the base-emitter junction), then they can be "stolen". That`s all? Really? What would be the current gain in this case?

Comment: @Saif once the base is at the same potential as the emitter then there will be no net flow of charge across the emitter-base junction so there will be no charge carrier gradient across the base to push carriers towards the collector-base junction.

Comment: @Saif also leakage current across the collector-base junction can raise the voltage of the floating base high enough to drive current flow across the emitter-base junction and create "real" transistor amplification action. This is used in phototransistors, for example, where the "leakage" current comes from photogenerated carriers.

Comment: On further reading I think I understand you. The emitter base junction's voltage stops the electrons from emitter to go into base. On connecting it to main circuit, if voltage of cell is lesser than voltage of emitter base junction then electrons will probably not flow from emitter to base. Even if electrons flow from emitter to base, it will raise voltage of the emitter base junction making it even harder for electrons to flow from emitter to base until voltage of cell and voltage of emitter base junction become same, then no current flows. Am I going wrong?

Comment: There is also reverse bias, so the voltage of cell could be more higher than emitter base junction's voltage? I'm guessing

Comment: For the real transistor amplification action which you are talking about. The current will flow from base to emitter? I was reading about phototransistor and saw that it has p type material and n type material which together makes a diode. On shining light onto the diode, electrons from p type go into n type and current flows. So here p type will be base and n type will be emitter?